Displaying map route in Power BI by connecting two or more different table
Hello everyone i have two table, assuming i have two table
Table 1:



Flying ID
Origin City ID
Origin City
Destination City ID
Destination City




1
1
Sidoarjo
3
Berlin


2
2
Kulonprogo
4
Rotterdam



Table 2:



ID
City
Latitude
Longitude




1
Sidoarjo
-7.383079433082236
112.77431172339418


2
Kulonprogo
-7.896626745518592
110.06016107464185


3
Berlin
52.364990043425856
13.50118371347345


4
Rotterdam
51.95147948977219
4.43385635887624



I want to display its flying route in Power BI with Flow Map visualization tool
How can i implement in Power BI, one thing i know is manage relationship is to connecting the two table, but is there any alternative way?
